# How do I get certain value from Json in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdata

When I search for [This Link to JSON file](https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=EMINEMLFLOCKAFLOCKA&entity=song&limit=3) it doesn't return anything (resultCount = 0). Here is some code of what I am trying to do.

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=EMINEMLFLOCKAFLOCKA&entity=song&limit=3" options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSString *resultCount = [JSON valueForKey:@"resultCount"];

// Does not return anything
NSLog(@"%@", resultCount);
```

I don't understand why the resultCount doesn't return anything. Doesn't this code store the value of it (0)? How do I retrieve data from resultCount? I'm trying to get values like 0, 1, 2, or 3 from it.

Comment: What do you mean by "resultCount doesn't return anything"? `resultCount` is an `NSNumber` (but you are erroneously using it as an `NSString`). It's not a function. What would you expect it to "return"? And how? **Did you look at the JSON delivered by this URL and realize that `resultCount` is indeed 0?**

Comment: A) Have you verified that `data` is non-null?  B) Have you verified that `JSON` is non-null?  C) Why are you not using the `error` parms?  D) Why do you not show us the value in `JSON`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It displays that there is nothing in data (if statement for !data runs). Does that mean I cannot get the resultCount value?

Comment: @abc123abc it means that `initWithContentsOfURL` failed. Check what's int `error`.

Comment: If there's nothing in `data` then there is something in `error`.  But you don't dump that, do you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you're not getting compiler warnings (and crashes) around this, but you have two problems:

1. You can't `initWithContentsOfUrl` with an `NSString`, you have to pass it an `NSURL`.
2. You should be parsing the `resultCount` as an `NSInteger` not an `NSString`.

Fixed:

```
NSError* error = [NSError new];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=EMINEMLFLOCKAFLOCKA&entity=song&limit=3"] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSInteger resultCount = [[JSON valueForKey:@"resultCount"] intValue];

// Logs 0
NSLog(@"%ld", resultCount);
```